# ImportError: OSError: .../lib/python3.9/site-packages/libpyg.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK5torch8autograd4Node4nameEv when I import pyg_lib

Tags: pytorch

I have installed v1.12.0 of PyTorch from source in an Anaconda environment.

```
>>> import torch
>>> print(torch.__version__)
1.12.0a0+git67ece03
>>>
>>> print(torch.version.cuda)
11.3
>>> print(torch.cuda.is_available())
True
>>> print(torch.cuda.device_count())
2
```

Here is a partial list from `conda list` :

```
$ conda list | grep cud
cudatoolkit               11.6.2              hfc3e2af_12    conda-forge
cudnn                     8.3.2.44             hed8a83a_1    conda-forge

$ conda list | grep torch
# packages in environment at /home/whp/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_compile_pt112cp39:
torch                     1.12.0a0+git67ece03          pypi_0    pypi
torch-scatter             2.1.0+pt112cu116          pypi_0    pypi
```

When I import pyg_lib,the following error occurs:

```
>>> import pyg_lib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/myDir/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyg_lib/__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    load_library('libpyg')
  File "/myDir/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyg_lib/__init__.py", line 36, in load_library
    torch.ops.load_library(spec.origin)
  File "/myDir/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_ops.py", line 255, in load_library
    ctypes.CDLL(path)
  File "/myDir/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /myDir/lib/python3.9/site-packages/libpyg.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK5torch8autograd4Node4nameEv
>>>
```

When I import torch_scatter,the following error occurs:

```
>>> import torch_scatter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/myDir/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch_scatter/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    torch.ops.load_library(spec.origin)
  File "/myDir/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/_ops.py", line 255, in load_library
    ctypes.CDLL(path)
  File "/myDir/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /myDir/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch_scatter/_version_cuda.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5torch3jit17parseSchemaOrNameERKSs
>>>
```

In another conda environment, I installed PyTorch through binaries：

```
conda install pytorch==1.12.0 torchvision==0.13.0 torchaudio==0.12.0 cudatoolkit=11.3 -c pytorch
```

and both packages can be referenced successfully.

What caused these errors?